# Triggering a link within iframe two levels down

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have this situation:

```
<div id="main">
  <a href="/page3" id="page3">Page3</a>
  <iframe id="iframe1" scr="blablabla">
     <a id="link1" href="#">Click Here</a>
     <iframe src="blablabla" id="iframe2">
        <a id="link2" href="#">Click Here</a>
     </iframe>
  </iframe>
</div>
```

So as you can see i have there three links.

I need to be able when the link id=link2 to trigger a click of a link id=page3

By this code:

parents.top.$('#page3')[0].click();

i am able to get it working from within the first iframe (so basically one level down), but i can't find a way to trigger a link two levels down.

BTW All of this is on the same server.

Thanks a lot

Jan

Comment: Is that even valid HTML? I am not sure you can add an iframe inside an iframe like that rather add the second iframe inside the body of the first iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a function in the second level frame that communicates with its parent.  So the the third level frame calls that function which then acts on the top level page.

Comment: Thanks @qw3n, that makes sense. I'll definitely try that. Any idea if there is a simpler solution? like something similar to what i posted in the question (parents.top.$('#page3')[0].click();) ???

Comment: @Stejsi I doubt it since I think the iframe is restricted to talking only to its parent or any of its children.  Or in other words in can only talk to frames that are directly related to it. With the page structure you have I think this is the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the closest() and trigger methods.  In this case you want a click handler for your id=link2 that looks like:

```
$(this).closest("#page3").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have nesting correct you can access iframes like this

```
window.parent[0]
window.parent[1]
```